# How can I start a basic automation environment or template using Selenium WebDriver on Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What files and/or applications do I need to download/install for me to start a basic webdriver automation environment? I'm using Eclipse as my IDE. And I would like to start a automation testing on Firefox browser.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the below url.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Got to "Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings" section. Download Java version.

Then just put the libraries from the downloaded file in your Java project library in eclipse. 
Start coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Let me write code you a sample code for automation for facebook automation. First you need to download the jars and include the dependent jars provided in the link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ .

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;


public class Facebook_login {
public static void main(String[]args){
    WebDriver wb=new HtmlUnitDriver();
    wb.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    wb.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Your email");
    wb.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("Your Password");
    WebElement button=wb.findElement(By.id("u_0_d"));
    button.submit();
    String f=wb.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(f);
     }

 }
```

you can use FirefoxDriver() instead of HtmlUnitDriver(). Actually HtmlUnitDriver is lightest . So i used it.